# how to show selected multiple options of drop down in php

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, html-select

First see my code.

```
   <select multiple name='assign_to[]'>
                    <?
                $result_10 = mysql_query("select * from login_users") or die(mysql_error());
                while($row_10 = mysql_fetch_object($result_10))
                {
                    echo "<option  value=".$row_10->user_id.">".$row_10->username."</option>";
                }
                ?>
    </select>
```

I am able to get value when page is submitted no issue with this but my problem is :

When page is submitted I am redirecting to the same page then I want that options which are selected before submitting the form will seen selected after page is submitted.

What PHP code is to written there. What I did for **single selected** drop down as :

```
<?
while($row_10 = mysql_fetch_object($result_10))
                    {
?>
       <option <?=$row_10->user_id==$_POST['assign_to']?'selected':''?> value="<?=$row_10->user_id?>"><?=$row_10->username?></option>
<?
                    }

?>
```

Hope you are getting my question ?

Thanks!!!

Comment: `$row_10->user_id == $_POST['assign_to']` did you mean `==` instead of `=` ?

Comment: @Mogria I edited question. I am able to do for single but I need multiple selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(in_array($row_10->user_id,$_POST['assign_to'])){echo "selected"}else{echo ""}
```

As your $_POST['assign_to'] is an array i guess this will work.

OR you can use conditional operators :

```
<option <?= in_array($row_10->user_id,$_POST['assign_to']) ? 'selected' : ''?> value="<?=$row_10->user_id?>"><?=$row_10->username?></option>
```

Comment: how to use this with option can you write the full code with <option>

Comment: `<option <?= in_array($row_10->user_id,$_POST['assign_to']) ? 'selected' : ''?> value="<?=$row_10->user_id?>"><?=$row_10->username?></option>`

Comment: @PrasanthBendra I have updated conditional statement line as parenthesis closing was missing! please update yours also :)

Comment: @Venu : :D, you got it.  +1 for that :D

Answer (score 1):

Use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
  <option <?=$row_10->user_id=$_POST['assign_to']?'selected':''?> value="<?=$row_10->user_id?>"><?=$row_10->username?></option>
```

replace with

```
<option <?= (in_array($row_10->user_id,$_POST['assign_to'])) ? 'selected' : ''?> value="<?=$row_10->user_id?>"><?=$row_10->username?></option>
```

You will get the selected values as an array, so check the value exists in an array.

Comment: Sorry I updated my answer, there was one parenthesis missing. now it should work!

Answer (score 1):

As you are using multiple select box, you will receive array of values in POST variable,
so you need to check if the value exists in that array instead of equating it

You can try in_array function as shown below:

```
<?
while($row_10 = mysql_fetch_object($result_10))
         {
         ?>
         <option <?=in_array($row_10->user_id,$_POST['assign_to'])?'selected':''?> value="<?=$row_10->user_id?>"><?=$row_10->username?></option>
         <?
         }
?>
```